# c# Prevent dragging box over another

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop

I am using visual studio. In my program I have the option for a user to activate certain widgets that they want to have. Each widget is a UserControl, so when they click to show a widget, it is activating the corresponding user control. Once they activate the control, they can drag the boxes wherever they wish so that they can customize how their screen looks. However, whenever you drag one widget over another, it just stacks them on top of each other, and this is not what I want. If I am dragging a box and it touches another one, I want it to stop and not be able to overlap it. How can I do this? I suspect it has something to do with the "DragOver" event, but not for sure.

Comment: Just implement a hit test.  As you're moving, call on a method that checks to see if the `Rectangle` (Bounds) of the one moving overlaps (IntersectsWith) any other, and prevent movement when `true`.

Comment: I want to check and see if a certain usercontrol intersects with any other usercontrol that is in the form, I cant figure out how to code it. I want to do `if (this.Bounds.IntersectsWith(*Any other usercontrol*))` then `*code to stop dragging*`

Answer (score 0):

The DragOver event will be raised on these case :
[+] If the user moves out of a window, the DragLeave event is raised.
[+] If the mouse enters another control, the DragEnter for that control is raised.
[+]If the mouse moves but stays within the same control, the DragOver event is raised.

If this is the event that you want, so try to terminate the widget (User Control) on UserControl_DragOver.

You can terminate your UserControl like this :

```
private void Btn_Cancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Parent.Controls.Remove(this);       
    }
```

*(If you mean sth else, tell in comment)*

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what I want. I want to check and see if a certain usercontrol intersects with any other usercontrol that is in the form, I cant figure out how to code it. I want to do `if (this.Bounds.IntersectsWith(*Any other usercontrol*))` then `{*stops object from overlapping*}`